# Hiding div when is submitted and send values to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<?php
echo $_POST['textvalue'];
echo $_post['radiovalue'];

?>
<div id="hidethis">
<form method="POST" action="">
<label>Tekst Value</label>
<input type="text" name="textvalue">
<label>Radio Value</label>
<input type="radio" name="radiovalue" value="autogivevalue">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bjk89/2/ here is it with the jQuery.

What i try to do is to hide the `<div id="hidethis">` when it's clicking `submit`.

I know i can make another page where i can recieve the values without the `<form>` section, but i want to put both in one page, make the `<div id="hidethis">` hidden after `submit`.

So i'll be able to get `echo $_POST['textvalue'];` and `echo $_post['radiovalue'];` as results

**RESULT MUST BE LIKE**

A Text // This is the value you input into Tekst Value

autogivevalue // This is the value from the radio button

----- INVISIBLE -----

```
<form is hidden because we set it in jQuery so>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. No need to use jQuery here.

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
    echo $_POST['textvalue'];
    echo $_post['radiovalue'];
} else {
?>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <label>Tekst Value</label>
        <input type="text" name="textvalue">
        <label>Radio Value</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radiovalue" value="autogivevalue">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You could even use `<form method="POST" action="" onsubmit="$('#hidethis').hide()">` to hide it even a bit sooner ;-)

Comment: But if the form submits, the page reloads, and then the div is shown again, no?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding '#' in your jquery code. Your version does not have # next to submit. Also your form is missing a closing tag here and in your JSFiddle code.

Try this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {   
         $('form').submit();
         $('#hidethis').hide();  
    });
});
</script>
    <form method='post' id="hidethis" name='form'>
        <input type="text" name="textvalue">
        <input type="radio" name="radiovalue" value="1">
        <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```